# Flex Builder Bandwidth profiling

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder, action

I was trying to find a bandwidth profiler in flex like there used to be one in Flash but couldn't really find one. Is there a way, that I can do bandwidth profiling of my local swf?

I'm using Flex Bulider with a AS3 project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flex Builder doesn't have this feature.  But you can just use Firebug for this.